# C++ converting reference to base pointer to reference to derived pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have this problem:

```
// the classes
class cBase {};
class cDerived : public cBase {};

class cBaseArray
{
    // the array of pointers to cBase
    cBase** array;

    // overloaded operator that returns an element of the array
    cBase*& operator[](unsigned index)
    {
        // much more complicated, but simplified for example
        return array[index];
    }
};

class cDerivedArray : public cBaseArray
{
    // overloaded operator that returns a converted element of the array
    cDerived*& operator[](unsigned index)
    {
        // conversion required, but don't know how
        return static_cast<???>(cBaseArray::operator[](index));
    }
};
```

So how do I convert the reference to pointer to `cBase` returned by the `operator[]` of `cBaseArray` to refernce to pointer to `cDerived` that can be returned by the `operator[]` of `cDerivedArray`?

Comment: You should [cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

Comment: Well-formatted code on SO? Did that really happen?

Comment: Just a friendly note. Usually casting this way indicates some problems with the design of the application, also returning a reference to a pointer looks really weird and is asking for much [Fun](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Losing). It also takes much effort to keep track and ensure correctness of types.

Comment: @luk32: I never return reference to pointers and I rarely use references in my code since I prefer the pointers, but the format of operator[] requires that so it can do both read/write. Maybe I should give up the comfort of "operator[]" and just use Set and Get for my classes which could be easily polymorphed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a reference, it must be a reference to a particular object. A `cDerived*&` must refer to an actual `cDerived*` (i.e. it must be an lvalue). Since you do not have any `cDerived*`, you cannot return a reference to one.

If you don't need to support the syntax `myDerived[4] = anotherPtr;` then you can just return `cDerived *`, which is no problem.  If you must return a reference then you have no simple option other than to return `cBase *&`, and require the caller to do a `dynamic_cast<>` on the result if they want to access things that are not accessible through the `cBase *`.

It would be possible to design a special object that `cDerived::operator[]` returns and holds a reference to `cBase *`; and that object has `operator=` defined which can take a `cDerived *`, and that object has a conversion operator to `cDerived *`.  This is added complication, I'd recommend not do to it unless you are really unhappy with the solution of my previous paragraph

NB. To get polymorphic behaviour you must have `cBase` be polymorphic, i.e. contain at least one virtual function - I'm assuming you intended this but left it out for brevity's sake.

Comment: I gave up my answer, the design it's a bit contrived and would probably need a bigger re-structuring. These are good suggestions so +1, the OP will have to do some book-keeping by himself.

Comment: I see... I was hoping that the compiler can create a temporary cast object that can be returned, I was trying to avoid exactly what you said - forcing the caller to do the casting. I needed the fully functionality of the operator[] because it will access a complex dynamic array for both read and write while I was also trying to avoid the use of templates for different types supported by the array.

Comment: If the compiler did create a temporary object, then doing `myDerived[4] = anotherPtr;` would update the temporary object, not the internal array member

Comment: No, it would be correct, because it would return a reference to a temporary (cast) pointer that would only point to the array member I need to access, so myDerived[4] = anotherPtr would directly change the array, but maybe c++ standard does not allow for such operation. It's pity I can't control operator overloading as I require :(

Answer (score 3):

You have to `dynamic_cast` them.